# Como executar um por vez itens de um array em sequência utilizando Promise - Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, promises

Possuo um array em que quero executar cada item, porém um só poderá iniciar após finalizar o anterior. O exemplo abaixo está imprimindo na sequência **2000,5000,10000** o que me faz entender que os três itens foram executados simultaneamente. Gostaria que cada item iniciasse apenas após a finalização do anterior. Esperava que fosse impresso **10000,5000,2000**.

```
const durations = [10000, 5000, 2000]

const timeOut = (t) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(t)
            resolve(true)
        }, t)
    })
}

for (let index = 0; index < durations.length; index++) {
    const element = durations[index];
    timeOut(element);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode esperar o retorno de cada promise. Fiz da seguinte forma, utilizando o [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) e [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), dessa forma o loop no array irá aguardar o retorno da sua promise para cada item.

```js
const durations = [10000, 5000, 2000]

const timeOut = (t) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t));
}

const init = async () => {
  for(i = 0; i < durations.length; i++) {
    const element = durations[i];
    await timeOut(element);
    console.log(element);
  }
}

init();
```

O problema do seu é que o `for` não está aguardando o retorno de suas `promise`, dessa forma ele irá executar todos os elementos de uma vez.

Outra forma simplificada de escrever seu código

```js
const durations = [10000, 5000, 2000]

const timeOut = (t) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t));

const init = async () => {
  for(const element of durations) {
    await timeOut(element);
    console.log(element);
  }
}

init();
```

Comment: Valeu!!! Sua resposta me ajudou muito a resolver a chamada de API que eu estava fazendo, e todas estavam sendo feitas em paralelo, sem respeitar a sequência do array. Obrigado.